# Can ProGuard make subclass' field name differ to superclass'

Tags: java, proguard, android-proguard

Suppose I have these classes:

```
public class Superclass {
    private int intValue;
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private String stringValue;
}
```

ProGuard may obfuscate them to be:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
}

public class B extends A {
    private String a;
}
```

Can I make `B.a` become another name not exists in its superclass, e.g. `B.b`? My classes are about to be used in serialization (JSON), stored locally so that I don't need the original field name, just need them to be different.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should keep the classes used in serialization.
[Processing serializable classes](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#serializable) suggests that you should write something like:

```
 -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable { 
 private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields; 
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream); 
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream); 
 java.lang.Object writeReplace(); 
 java.lang.Object readResolve(); 
}
```